# SFNode field in Proto

Tags: x3d

I've got these `DEF`s in my X3D file:

```xml
    <ImageTexture DEF="texture1" URL="some/image1.png" />
    ...
    <ImageTexture DEF="texture2" URL="some/image2.png" />
```

I wish to `USE` these in my `ProtoInstance`s so that I don't have to create a texture node for each (with the corresponding http request for each), by referencing them by name in one of the proto fiels. Something like this:

```xml
    <ProtoDeclare name="myProto">
        <ProtoInterface>
            <field name="texture" type="SFString" accessType="initializeOnly" />
        </ProtoInterface>
        <ProtoBody>
            ...
            <!-- obviously this doesn't work, but you get the idea: -->
            <ImageTexture USE="${texture}" />
            ...
        </ProtoBody>
    </ProtoDeclare>
    
    ...

    <ProtoInstance name="myProto">
        <FieldValue name="texture" value="texture1" />
    </ProtoInstance>
```

I have tried with `IS` within the proto set to the one already defined, but it doesn't work for me:

```xml
    <ProtoDeclare name="myProto">
        <ProtoInterface>
            <field name="texture" type="SFNode" accessType="initializeOnly" />
        </ProtoInterface>
        <ProtoBody>
            ...
            <Appearance>
                <IS><connect nodeField="texture" protoField="texture"/></IS>
            </Appearance>
            ...
        </ProtoBody>
    </ProtoDeclare>
    
    ...

    <ProtoInstance name="myProto">
        <FieldValue name="texture">
            <ImageTexture USE="texture1" />
        </FieldValue>
    </ProtoInstance>
```

I have also tried with a `Script`, but cannot find a way to make the link.

Any ideas are very welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `IS` solution *does* work. My problem was a different one. The `url` of my textures was not properly written. **Texture url is a `MFString`, so I had to enclose the value in additional single quotes**, like this:

```xml
<ImageTexture DEF="texture1" URL='"some/image1.png"' />
...
<ImageTexture DEF="texture2" URL='"some/image2.png"' />
```

Note that at least in my case, with X_ITE as the browser, using quotes the other way round (double quotes around single quotes) did not work.